# Webench PSU Design Schematics

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

quick question about the Webench designer. I have generated a design for a 5V switching PSU, and the schematic shows a couple of the caps with "Qty = 2", does this mean I should put 2 of them in series where the symbol is or something?

[image: Webench schematic]

Comment: Do you understand what happens when 2x RC values are in series vs parallel?

Comment: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-13/series-and-parallel-capacitors/#:~:text=With%20resistors%2C%20series%20connections%20result,connections%20result%20in%20diminished%20values.

Comment: But what I don't understand is, why not put a single 20uF capacitor in place of two 10uF?

Comment: @Jaska But you never asked that. I edited my answer.

Comment: Jaska , I'm sure you understand the formula for attenuation of series shunt resistors and you know what RC=T means and some constant k  such that f-3dB =1/kT  , have you ever tried to compare T's for 10uF and 20 uF caps or 22u, 44uF or 100nF and 50 nF caps. Do you know why they differ? and the signficance if it?  Size ,chemistry, ripple?  think about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The design calls for the given quantity of the specified caps.

They are not to be put in series as per your question.

They are to be put in parallel.

Since a certain amount of ideal capacitance is needed to keep voltage ripple low enough, physical capacitances are not ideal as they have series resistance and series inductance. Using multiple smaller capacitors to get the required capacitance means the effects of ESR and ESL are lower.

Comment: OK thanks. So, for example, the Cout cap should actually be two 22uF caps placed in parallel?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your help